Events In Progression Problem Excel Power Pivot/Data Model DAX question
I am working in Excel with power pivot.
I have 2 tables: a calendar table and a data table.
The calendar table has 3 relationships with the data table.
In the data table, there are 3 date fields: Case Sent, Due By, Entrance Date.(the Case Sent/Calendar is the active [main] relationship).
I am trying to portray the history of overdue cases from month-to-month - how it is growing or diminishing.
I tried the following measure, but it is not giving me the cumulative monthly total I want (trying to portray the overdue case count progression from month to month:
Backlog2:=CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('RS Cases'),
        USERELATIONSHIP(Date_Table[Date],'RS Cases'[Due By]),
FILTER(
    ALL('RS Cases'[Due By],'RS Cases'[Entrance Date]), -- returns all the rows in a table, or all the values of a column while ignoring any existing filter that might have been applied.
    
        [Due By]<=MAX(Date_Table[Date]) && --Due by Date is less or equal to the last day of the month
        (
            ISBLANK([Entrance Date]) || -- Entrance date is null or 
            'RS Cases'[Entrance Date]>MAX(Date_Table[Date]) -- Entrance date is greater than the last day of the month
        )
    )
)

The number produced do not make sense. I already know it should increase from month to month and the overall total overdue cases should be 5,633 - based on filtering the data table.
enter image description here

I think changing `ALL('RS Cases'[Due By],'RS Cases'[Entrance Date]) to ALL('RS Cases') should do it:
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('RS Cases'),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Date_Table[Date], 'RS Cases'[Due By]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('RS Cases'),
        'RS Cases'[Due By] <= MAX(Date_Table[Date]) && 
        (ISBLANK('RS Cases'[Entrance Date]) || 'RS Cases'[Entrance Date] > MAX(Date_Table[Date]))
    )
)


Thank you for the reply. I think I did not have a good understanding of what I needed when I originally posted.  Here is an expression I created that lists the 3 filter conditions I need it to sum in order to determine the total backlog for that month:
